# JQuery Autocomplete malfunction

Tags: jquery, function

*First time posting so I apologise for any mistakes and for if this has been answered before.*

There might be something obvious that I've missed but this function doesn't filter the list of variables. When I enter "0" it shows nothing, but then when I type "j" (and a few other characters such as "e", "c" and "b") the function shows everything in the array.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function()
    {
        var data = [{"Part_no":"0001","Part_description":"Part 1"},{"Part_no":"0002","Part_description":"Part 2"}]

        $( "#project" ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 1,
            source: data,
            select: function( event, ui )
            {
                $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.Part_no );
                $( "#project-description" ).html( ui.item.Part_description );

                return false;
            }
        })
        .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item )
        {
          return $( "<li>" )
            .append( "<div>" + item.Part_no + "<br>" + item.Part_description + "</div>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
        };
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="project">
</body>
```

Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 2):

I think the format of the data passed is not correct. As per this documentation http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source . You need to pass the array of the string or array of the object with label and value properties. So you have to decide what you want to search on "Part No" or "Part Description". In case you want the auto complete only on the part No , pass on that as array

```
         var data = ["001","002","003""];
```

create another array for the detail description

```
         var desc = ["Desc 1 " ,"Desc 2" , "Desc 3"];
```

So once user select the data , you will get the position of the data or the value that you can map into the desc array to get more detail you want to use.

Comment: I think the link you provided gave me the answer. I changed "Part_no" to "label" in both the data source and the output and this fixed the issue... Do you know if there is a way to set "Use "Part_no" as "label"" or something similar? (I can't change Part_no to label in my actual data)

Comment: In answer to the data not being passed correctly. I used this guide: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that the process was looking for a "label" array key.

Changing all instances of "Part_no" to "label" fixed the issue. I did this using array_map() in PHP but if anyone knows how to do this in JQuery I would very much like to know.